# Silverlight DataGrid selection and drag-drop

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid, silverlight-toolkit

I am currently implementing drag and drop using the DataGrid provided in the Silverlight SDK and I want the user to be, easily, able to drag multiple items to another list.

The grid's selection gets updated on the **MouseDown** event so the only way the user have to drag multiple items is to press **Shift** while begining the drag operation. This is not really obvious and, for me, the natural way whould have been to just click the selected block of rows and drag them. To do so, the selection needs to be updated on the **MouseUp** event.

I've tried to derive from the DataGrid to inject my custom DataGridRows but the DataGrid doesn't expose a way to replace the type of rows it creates.

Anyone have a solution or ideas for this?

Thank you,

Jacques.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's unfortunate that the selection is updated on mousedown.   You will need to perform some work in the mousedown event to work around this.   This codeproject article should help:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/338594/Drag-drop-multiple-selected-rows-of-datagridview-w